# SQLSTATE[42S02] + SQLSTATE[42S22] netflix clone

Tags: php, mysql, netflix

thank you for taking look at my problem, I cannot describe how bad I feel, if you could help me, I would be so happy.

I was doing website from udemy course name "Create Netflix clone" It worked fine on my Xampp on localhost but when I publish it on hostprovider-> [www.dingy.cz](http://www.dingy.cz) I have got problem

**PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dingyczcz.dingyczczvideoProgress' doesn't exist in **/www/doc/www.dingy.cz/www/includes/classes/VideoProvider.php** on line **43****

since I am just learing everything I am pretty lost, even if I am trying to google asnwers,

this is my code in VideoProvider.php :

```
//<?php
//class VideoProvider {
    public static function getUpNext($con, $currentVideo) {
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM videos
                            WHERE entityId=:entityId AND id != :videoId
                            AND (
                                (season = :season AND episode > :episode) OR season > :season
                            )
                            ORDER BY season, episode ASC LIMIT 1");
        $query->bindValue(":entityId", $currentVideo->getEntityId());
        $query->bindValue(":season", $currentVideo->getSeasonNumber());
        $query->bindValue(":episode", $currentVideo->getEpisodeNumber());
        $query->bindValue(":videoId", $currentVideo->getId());
        
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowCount() == 0) {
            $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM videos
                                    WHERE season <=1 AND episode <= 1
                                    AND id != :videoId
                                    ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 1");
            $query->bindValue(":videoId", $currentVideo->getId());
            $query->execute();
        }

        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return new Video($con, $row);
    }



//32line    public static function getEntityVideoForUser($con, $entityId, $username) {
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT videoId FROM `videoProgress` 
                                INNER JOIN videos
                                ON videoProgress.videoId = videos.id
                                WHERE videos.entityId = :entityId
                                AND videoProgress.username = :username
                                ORDER BY videoProgress.dateModified DESC
                                LIMIT 1");

        $query->bindValue(":entityId", $entityId);
        $query->bindValue(":username", $username);
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowCount() == 0) {
            $query = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM videos
                                    WHERE entityId=:entityId
                                    ORDER BY season, episode ASC LIMIT 1");
            $query->bindValue(":entityId", $entityId);
            $query->execute();
        }

//53line        return $query->fetchColumn();
    }
}
?>
```

and here is my mysqldatabse

[image: mysqldatabase]

and if I create database with name dingyczczvideoProgress
I am getting another message:

**PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'videoProgress.username' in 'where clause' in **/www/doc/www.dingy.cz/www/includes/classes/VideoProvider.php** on line **43****

[image: mysqldingyczczvideoProgress]

Comment: `dingyczczvideoProgress` isn't seen in the code, which is line 43 of that file?

Comment: from 32 line public static function getEntityVideoForUser($con, $entityId, $username) {
 to end 56 line: return $query->fetchColumn();

Comment: 43//  $query->execute();